# Div is not growing to the Reportviewer content in IE7

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-7, reportviewer

I am using div tag to display ssrs report. There are 2 rows(div). The second div contains float style to display button in left side. The First div contains report view to display the report. This grows according to the content in the report in all the browsers expect IE7.

Update:

Only div is not growing to reportviewr content. i have tested with raw content inside the div. it is working fine in IE7. but it is not working for Reportviewer content.

Code:

```
<div id='divMain' class='maincontent'>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewerControl" runat="server" DocumentMapWidth="100%" CssClass="fixScrollBarBug"
    Height="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" AsyncRendering="false" ShowCredentialPrompts="False"
    InteractivityPostBackMode="AlwaysSynchronous" SizeToReportContent="false" ShowPageNavigationControls="True"  >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
   <div style="float: right; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right: 10px">
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnReportClose" runat="server" TabIndex="5" CausesValidation="false"
    Width="55px" Height="29px">
    <Image ImageUrl="btn_Close_Default.png" HoveredImageUrl="btn_Close_Over.png"
        PressedImageUrl="btn_Close_Hit.png" IsBackgroundImage="true" />
</telerik:RadButton>
</div>

<style type='text/css'>
.maincontent
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fixScrollBarBug div div div
    {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me. position:relative with height solved my problem

Code:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.maincontent
{        
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
}

</style>
<div id='divMain' class="maincontent" >
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewerControl" runat="server" DocumentMapWidth="100%" CssClass="fixScrollBarBug"
Height="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" AsyncRendering="false" ShowCredentialPrompts="False"
InteractivityPostBackMode="AlwaysSynchronous" SizeToReportContent="false" ShowPageNavigationControls="True"  >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
<div style="float: right; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right: 10px">
 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnReportClose" runat="server" TabIndex="5" CausesValidation="false"
Width="55px" Height="29px">
<Image ImageUrl="btn_Close_Default.png" HoveredImageUrl="btn_Close_Over.png"
    PressedImageUrl="btn_Close_Hit.png" IsBackgroundImage="true" />
 </telerik:RadButton>
 </div>
```